# Convert values in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

**What I want to do**

I want to convert values in `DataFrame`.

**Example**

Using dictionary is what I came up with (but didn't succeed).  In this example, the key of the dictionary is what I want to change from, while the value of the dictionary is what I want to change to.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 'A'], [2, 2, 'B'], [3, 3, 'C']], index=['I_1', 'I_2', 'I_3'], columns=['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3'])

#      C_1  C_2 C_3
# I_1    1    1   A
# I_2    2    2   B
# I_3    3    3   C

## dictionary to convert data in column `C_3`
conv = {'A':'D', 'B':'E', 'C':'F'}

## !! DO SOMETHING !!

## Expected output (Values in `C_3` are changed.)
#      C_1  C_2 C_3
# I_1    1    1   D
# I_2    2    2   E
# I_3    3    3   F
```

Comment: `df['C_3'] = df['C_3'].map(conv)`

Comment: Just use `df['C_3'] = df['C_3'].map(conv)`